# Update-manager fails silently on 14.04

Tags: 14.04, lubuntu, update-manager

I recently reinstalled a lubuntu from scratch, to upgrade to 14.04. Everything's working as expected, except for the update-manager that silently fails when trying to upgrade my system's packages.

It does correctly list the packages to be upgraded, I can then click on the "Install now" button (or something like this, I'm running a French flavour of Ubuntu). When I click the button, it seems unresponsive for 5 to 10 seconds, then the upgrade dialog with the progress bar appears, displays *"Loading package list"*, then very shortly something about *"authentication"* (not long enough so that I can read it).. and closes.

The install is fresh and I have no idea where to look. I tried launching update-manager in a term but it doesn't display any error when it fails, only this message when the window first shows up :

```
** (update-manager:3642): WARNING **: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-m0jkFlZ3yo: Connexion refusée.
```

Any idea where this might come from ? I can upgrade the packages using the command line and `sudo apt-get` but this is not my computer, and I do not wish its owner to have to do this to upgrade the packages.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Can you run the update processes from a terminal?  `sudo apt-get update` and then when it finishes, `sudo apt-get upgrade`

Comment: Yep, as stated in my question (maybe not very clearly :)), I can do it and it's working. I tried it some days ago to see if it could solve issues with some package that might be causing this error, but didn't do any good. The upgrade worked though. I'd rather not do it again or I won't have any update pending in my update manager ;)

Comment: Sorry - I had not noted that.  I tend to only use the command line myself...

Comment: Yeah no worries ! I don't mind using the command line, but this computer is not mine and the user won't be willing to deal with any command line stuff, even if it's quite simple. Hence my question.

Comment: There are two other frontends for Update Manager `-kde` and `-text`. Do both fail similarly? Perhaps one of them may provide more data.

Comment: I did not know about this, it provides a bit more data indeed ! When I launch ``update-manager-text`` without ``sudo`` (like the graphical ``update-manager``), I get a permission error, saying it can't open the lock file ``/var/lib/dpkg/lock`` for ``/var/lib/dpkg/`` directory (the file is owned by root:root and has 600 perms). I've tried to change the owner group and the perms to 660 so that the ``admin`` group can write this file, but I get other errors (I'm not sure this is the right way to go anyway).

Comment: I have the same issue in Xubuntu 15.10.

Comment: Looks like in my case the updates were not installed because they were "held back". Now some other updates were correctly installed by `update-manager` without asking me for authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Hello again an other solution is better than previous is try to an other profile to your computer for example create another user test1 and test it , maybe work that.

Comment: That's an idea. I'll try it tonight.

Answer (score -1):

Hello my idea is first backup your profile then clean your partition linux system and try it again ,second solution is format your file system of linux.
third solution is auto remove package your unneeded package or clean then try again

Comment: Well reinstall the OS seems like a really radical solution (and won't teach us anything about the issue). This is my last resort. I tried the package removing thing, but it did no good.